# Need help to fetch json data with Axios dependancy for react

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need help using the axios dependancy on react.
I'm fetching data from this endpoint:  https://api.covid19api.com/summary

I setup  a config for my API (config.jsx)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({   
    baseURL: `https://api.covid19api.com/summary`,
    responseType: "json" 
});
```

then i call it in my App, (a class component) as API

```
import API from './config.jsx';
```

and execute it within my ComponentDidMount()

```
 componentDidMount() {
    API.get().then(res => {     
      const countries = JSON.stringify(res.data.Countries);
      //console.log(countries);
      this.setState({ covid: countries });
      console.log(`Etat du state:  ${this.state.covid}`);
    })
}
```

I get the data, store it in my state named 'covid', but when it comes to map over the results i get an error "TypeError Cannot read property 'map' of null" I think i have to convert the  data into an array but i don't know how to do this .

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>{this.state.appliname}</h1>

          {this.state.covid.map(item => (
            <div>{item.Country}</div>
          ))}

        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Here's the full script on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-faraday-ykewv?file=/src/App.js

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things you need to consider:

1. **Always handle errors in promises**. Sometimes you may face API failure, so you should handle the API request gets failed that we should do. So simply add a [`catch`](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) handler to your promise chain.
2. **You should always handle first data initiation**. In the first render of your page, there is no `this.state.covid` so you can't pass it to your view and map through it, so if you do this it will throw an error. To make this work you should add [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to your element.
3. **Define your first state initiation correctly**. Since you expect your `this.state.covid` to be an array, so you should define it as an array in the first place (`this.state = {covid: []}`).
4. **Avoid passing [`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)s to [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**. When you try to convert your incoming items from API to JSON with `JSON.stringify(res.data.Countries)` it will make your data as JSON. Since JSON comes with string type it won't fit array helpers like `Array#map`, when you got your data there is no need to make JSON of the. If in any case, your incoming data was JSON itself you should parse it with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

**Working demo**:

[image: CodeSandbox]

Answer (score 1):

1. Set init state default array

> this.state = {   covid: [],   appliname: "CovidFacts" };

2. Set countries

> ```
> const countries = res.data.Countries;
> ```

Follow all :

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import API from "./config.jsx";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      covid: [],
      appliname: "CovidFacts"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    API.get().then(res => {
      const countries = res.data.Countries;
      this.setState({ covid: countries });
      console.log(`Etat du state:  ${this.state.covid}`);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1>{this.state.appliname}</h1>
          {this.state.covid.map(item => (
            <div>{item.Country}</div>
          ))}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```